# База данных в проекте Android

Tags: android, sql, база-данных

Помогите разобраться со следующей проблемой. Я новичок в создании приложений Android, только разбираюсь с основными моментами. Я написал приложение "кредитный калькулятор". Вводишь сумму кредита, процентную ставку и срок кредита, на выходе получаешь ежемесячный платеж и совокупный платеж. Теперь я хочу прикрутить к моему приложению локальную базу данных. Структура базы данных: название банка - ставки процента, которые он предлагает - сроки, на которые он предлагает кредит. То есть я хочу, чтобы приложение работало так: вводишь сумму кредита сам, далее из раскрывающегося списка выбираешь банк (ну там Сбербанк, Альфабанк и т.д.), и процентную ставку и срок кредита можешь выбрать только те (из списка), которые есть в базе данных у этого банка. Расскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать это технически? Приложение само у меня на Java. Базу желательно на SQL сделать. Можно ли это вообще?
С уважением.

Comment: @user822346, смотри в сторону Room, Realm или вообще пиши на SQLite

Comment: можно использовать "сырую" SQLite (уроки [с 34-го по 39-ый](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html)), можно ORM, как Room (уроки [с 5-го по 13-ый](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components.html)). в контексте Java второй предпочтительней и удобнее, так как позволяет работать с объектами, а не "сырыми" выборками

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужна локальная БД, то смотрите ответы выше. Но еще посоветую вам риал тайм БД - Firebase. Нужен доступ к интернету, но для получения данных с БД надо всего несколько строк.